# New activity not opening using StartActivity Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-activity, onclick

I have a relative layout to which I have assigned an onClick function that when clicked should open a new activity. However, the app crashes when I try the below code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class));
```

However, it works fine when I print a toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My xml layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:onClick="newactivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

The method I am calling is:

```
public void newactivity (View v) {

    //Toast.makeText(this, "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class));
}
```

The method run fine if I comment the startActivity and uncomment the Toast (it prints Worked when the layout is clicked).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have also tried other ways of opening activity but still no luck:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                          at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4725)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Comment: is `newActivity` is registered in manifest ? plus post complete error details

Comment: the new activity didn't get registered, so I had to put it in manually. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the activity your calling in your manifest?

Comment: That worked. silly mistake. need to wait 9 mins before accepting answer!

Comment: Happens to all of us ;)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Voted up :) congratz on 1000+ rep

Comment: click listener won't work after removing `android:onClick="newactivity"`

Answer (score 1):

Declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml like this after your launcher activity declaration.

```
    <activity android:name=".NewActivity" />
```